# Insert data from VB net into Postgresql

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, ms-access

I'm trying to input data from my vb into PostgreSQL
the source is another database on Ms Access

im using this code for connection

```vb
Public Function LoadAcces_tblpibconr() As DataTable 'ganti ini sesuai nama table
    Dim Table As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Command.Connection = conn.OpenConnection()
    Command.CommandText = "select * from tblpibconr"
    Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    ReadRows = Command.ExecuteReader()
    Table.Load(ReadRows)
    ReadRows.Close()
    conn.CloseConexion()
    Return Table
End Function


'=====================================TABLE POSTGRESQL========================='
Public Function LoadNpgsql_tblpibconr() As DataTable
    Dim Table As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Cmd.Connection = connNpgsql.OpenConnection()
    Cmd.CommandText = "select * from tblpibconr"
    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    ReadRows1 = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Table.Load(ReadRows1)
    ReadRows1.Close()
    connNpgsql.CloseConexion()
    Return Table
End Function
```

I'm using this function for filtering the data
I'll compare the data first and take the data without a match and stored it into postgresql

```vb
Public Function CekData_tblpibconr(ByVal car As String, ByVal reskd As String, ByVal contno As String) As Boolean
    Dim Table As DataTable = New DataTable()

    Cmd.Connection = connNpgsql.OpenConnection()
    If Cmd.Parameters.Count > 0 Then
        Cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    End If
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car", car)
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reskd", reskd)
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contno", contno)
    Cmd.CommandText = <sql>select * from tblpibconr where car=@car and reskd=@reskd and contno=@contno</sql>.Value
    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    ReadRows1 = Cmd.ExecuteReader() 'ERROR System.InvalidOperationException: 'Parameter '@car' must have its value set'

    Table.Load(ReadRows1)
    ReadRows1.Close()
    If Table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
    Cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    connNpgsql.CloseConexion()
End Function



Sub bandingkan_data_tblpibconr()
    For i = 0 To DGV1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim validasi = query.CekData_tblpibconr(DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value, DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value) 'cek data dari access ke postgresql
        If validasi = True Then 'jika data di access tidaj ada
            'inser data
            Dim a As String
            If IsDBNull(DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString()) Then
                a = "0"
            Else
                a = DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString()
            End If
            DGV1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.MistyRose
            Dim Insertdata = query.insertNpgsql_tblpibconr(DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString(), DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString(), DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString() _
                              , DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString(), a)
            If Insertdata = True Then
                ' MsgBox("Masuk")
            Else
                MsgBox("Data Gagal DIMASUKAN")
            End If
        End If


    Next i
    LoadNpgsql_tblpibconr()
    MsgBox("Selesai")
End Sub
```

```vb
Public Function insertNpgsql_tblpibconr(ByVal car As String, ByVal reskd As String, ByVal contno As String, ByVal contukur As String, ByVal conttipe As String) As Boolean

    Cmd.Connection = connNpgsql.OpenConnection()
    If Cmd.Parameters.Count = 0 Then
        Cmd.Parameters.Clear()

    End If
    Try
        Cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblpibconr(car,reskd,contno,contukur,conttipe) values(@car,@reskd,@contno,@contukur,@conttipe)"
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car", car)
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reskd", reskd)
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contno", contno)
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contukur", contukur)
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conttipe", conttipe)
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        str = "insert into tblpibconr(car,reskd,contno,contukur,conttipe) values(@car , @reskd , @contno, @contukur, @conttipe)"
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try

    connNpgsql.CloseConexion()
End Function
```

this is the error that I get

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Parameter '@car' must have its
> value set'

ITS Refer to `ReadRows1 = Cmd.ExecuteReader()` on function `cekdata_tblpibconr` and `Dim validasi = query.CekData_tblpibconr(DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value, DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, DGV1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)` on sub `bandingkan_data_tblpibconr`

but this error appear after the data successfully inserted to my Postgresql

Comment: I could be wrong on this one, but the my feeling would be the problem might be in you're calling Returns from your methods before closing your connection.  My understanding is Return will immediately exit the function and not execute any code after it.  Maybe you need to restructure your connection handling to be enclosed in Using blocks

Comment: Keep your database objects local to the methods where they are used. Put them in `Using...End Using` blocks to be sure they are closed and disposed.

Comment: thanks, guys I'm ended using  ```If String.IsNullOrEmpty(DGV19.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value) ```Then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running the Function where the error occurred, I have checked if we really have a value for car.

This method demonstrates what I mean by keeping your database objects local. The connection and command are created locally in a `Using` block. They will be closed and disposed even it there is an error.

You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. Likewise, pass the command text and the connection to the constructor of the command. The default `CommandType` is `CommandType.Text` so it is not necessary to explicitly set that property.

Open the connection at the last possible moment directly before the command is executed.

```vb
Public Function CekData_tblpibconr(ByVal car As String, ByVal reskd As String, ByVal contno As String) As Boolean
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(car) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Car has no value")
        Return True '??
    End If
    Dim Table As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Using cn As New NpgsqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New NpgsqlCommand("select * from tblpibconr where car=@car and reskd=@reskd and contno=@contno;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@car", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = car
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@reskd", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = reskd
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@contno", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = contno
        cn.Open()
        Table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    If Table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```